# c++: BOOST_ASIO Server reply isn't as expected?

Tags: c++, client-server, boost-asio, output, reply

Basically I have a client where I send a string of 10 bytes `hellohello` to a server and within the server I expect the reply to be `0123456789` back to the client but instead I get `hellohello` again? I changed the `char data_` to `char data_out` on line 58 in the tcp_server.cpp because I thought that was the place to send packet data out? I'm pretty sure that gets called but for some reason things aren't working like I thought.

This is the server output,

```
handle read: bytes_transferred10
10
handle write:
0123456789
handle read: bytes_transferred0
```

I also wonder why did `handle read: bytes_transferred0` get called again?

This is the client output,

```
Enter message: hellohello
Reply is: hellohello

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.484 s
Press any key to continue.
```

This is the tcp_server.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
          socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);


private:
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
      std::cout<<"handle read: bytes_transferred"<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
    if (!error)
    {
          read_handler(error, bytes_transferred);
          boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
      std::cout<<"handle write: "<<std::endl;
      data_out = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    if (!error)
    {
            std::cout<<data_out<<std::endl;

            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_out, max_length),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
  char data_out[max_length];
};
void session::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
      std::cout<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;
}

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    start_accept();
  }


private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
    }
    else
    {
      delete new_session;
    }

    start_accept();
  }

  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server s(io_service, 4000);

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

tcp_client.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {


    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), "127.0.0.1", "4000");
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    tcp::socket s(io_service);
    s.connect(*iterator);

    using namespace std; // For strlen.
    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    char request[max_length];
    std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
    size_t request_length = strlen(request);
    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length));

    char reply[max_length];
    size_t reply_length = boost::asio::read(s,boost::asio::buffer(reply, request_length));
    std::cout << "Reply is: ";
    std::cout.write(reply, reply_length);
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your server passes the buffer it just read into from async_read() to async_write(). why do you expect the server to reply with 0123456789?

Comment: @SamMiller . Oh ok! So I replaced the old call inside `handle_read` with `data_out = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
          read_handler(error, bytes_transferred);
          boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(data_out, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));` and now it works but I still have no idea why `handle_write()` is called. Its completely useless then is it?

Comment: I think `handle_read()` calls `handle_write()` recursively? Is that the point?

Comment: When you call async_write() you set handle_write() as the handler. That is why handler_write() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment

> I think `handle_read()` calls `handle_write()` recursively?

is close but not quite correct as there is no recursion here. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html) explains this nicely:

> Regardless of whether the asynchronous operation completes immediately
>   or not, the handler **will not be invoked from within this function**.
>   Invocation of the handler will be performed in a manner equivalent to
>   using `boost::asio::io_service::post()`.

Added emphasis is mine. Instead of recursion, It is better to think of these concepts as chaining since one operation such as `async_write()` is initiated in the handler of another, such as `async_read()`. The exact specifics depend on the protocol in use.

If you want the server to send the string 0123456789 to the client, fill your buffer before invoking `async_write()`.